# JGit: git submodule foreach command

Tags: git, git-submodules, jgit

I know the support for git submodules is limited in JGit, but still was wondering how can I achieve this:

`git submodule foreach git checkout <branchName>`

and similar commands using JGit.

Or is there any other better Java based API for Git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JGit there is a `SubmoduleWalk` that might help with your problem. To run a checkout command on all submodules, you would write something along these lines:

```java
try (SubmoduleWalk walk = SubmoduleWalk.forIndex(repository)) {
  while(walk.next()) {
    try (Repository submoduleRepository = walk.getRepository()) {
      Git.wrap(submoduleRepository).checkout().call();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i see this "org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRefNameException: Branch name <null> is not allowed". any ideas?

Comment: @Srinivas  What have you done so far to solve the problem? If you need help please post a question with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://github.com/srinivasupadhya/git-cmd/blob/master/src/com/tw/go/plugin/jgit/JGitHelper.java - cloneOrFetch() - checkoutSubmodule() throws that exception

Comment: The issue here is that the submodule walk doesn't pull the child module's branch from the .gitsubmodules file to properly allow this checkout.

Comment: @Doug You are right, I seems like, in JGit, you need to manually read from the `.gitsubmodules` file (e.g. using `StoredConfig`) and pass the branch name to the `CheckoutCommand`. Regarding this topic, I've found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/git-submodules-specify-a-branch-tag) useful in that it explains what to do in native git.

Comment: is this issue is solved. I am passing branch-name,still getting null pointer exception

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your question. If you see the ÌnvalidRefNameException` as described in the firs comment, the issues is apparently not yet resolved. If you face a different problem, please provide more context or ask a new question if necessary.